# Eclipse RCP CSS styling does not work after export

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I followed the suggested steps in [this forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1133082/#msg_1133082) to get CSS themeing for the different OSs by copying the css and images folder from org.eclipse.platform.

It works fine when I launch it from Eclipse but when I export the product file (whether from Eclipse or via Maven), there is no CSS styling at all.

I have checked the build.properties and the css and images folder are marked for export so I do not understand why it is not finding them.

I am working on a 3.x RCP soft migrated into 4.x

```
<extension
     id="liteproduct"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        application="com.xyzide.rcp.application"
        name="XYZ IDE">
     <property
         name="applicationXMI"
         value="com.xyzide.rcp/LegacyIDE.e4xmi">
   </property>
     <property
           name="cssTheme"
           value="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default">
     </property>
  <property
         name="applicationCSSResources"
         value="platform:/plugin/com.xyzide.rcp/images/">
  </property>
  </product>
```

```
 <extension
point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme">
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_default.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default.noos"
        label="Default Theme">
        </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_classic_winxp.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_classic"
        label="Classic">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_default_gtk.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default"
        label="GTK"
        os="linux">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_default_mac.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default"
        label="Mac"
        os="macosx">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_default_win7.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default"
        label="Windows 7"
        os="win32"
        os_version="6.1">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_default_winxp_blu.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default"
        label="Windows XP Blue"
        os="win32">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_default_winxp_olv.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default.xpolive"
        label="Windows XP Olive"
        os="win32">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_classic_win7.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_classic"
        label="Windows 7 Classic"
        os="win32"
        os_version="6.1">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_default_gtk.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default"
        label="Solaris"
        os="solaris">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_default_gtk.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default"
        label="AIX"
        os="aix">
    </theme>
    <theme
        basestylesheeturi="css/e4_classic_winxp.css"
        id="com.xyzide.ui.css.theme.e4_default"
        label="HPUX"
        os="hpux">
    </theme>
</extension>
```

I have omitted some properties from the product extension that were not relevant.

Comment: What do you have in the plugin.xml which defines the product?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: The plugin.xml looks ok. Check that the exported product plugin does contain the css directory.

Comment: My product is made of two plugins: com.xyzide.plugin and com.xyzide.rcp. The latter is what contains the css files and in my exported product is a jar file so how will I check for the css folder? In my build.properties it is checked for export. Also, before this I had fixed styling and that worked fine (ApplicationCSS property)

Comment: Aha... I think I found it... for some reason I have to export it as a directory and not as a jar file and it seems to work. I don't know why it worked with ApplicationCSS because that had a css and images folder as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with greg-449's help, I was able to identify that when the RCP is exported, it needs to have the plugin containing the css and images folder packaged as a directory.

I added the following to my Manifest.MF

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

And when I exported, the styling worked fine. I tested it on Windows at least and it seemed ok. Will need to check the other OSs as well.

Comment: I think it can be made to work in a jar if you include `platform:/plugin/com.xyzide.rcp/` at the start of the `basestylesheeturi` values (at least that is what I have and it works).

Comment: Sorry this might be a silly question but are there any reasons why I would want to keep it as a jar and not a directory?

Comment: And you are right! How could I be so silly... I looked back at my old code for ApplicationCSS and that is how I have it. I guess I just used this code straight off the forum and didn't realise. Can you post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work in a jar if you include `platform:/plugin/com.xyzide.rcp/` at the start of the `basestylesheeturi` values.

Using a jar uses a bit less space but I notice the Eclipse install does use a directory (which might just be to make it easier to access the files for this). Eclipse does sometimes expand jars in to its cache, but I don't think that is done for the CSS and image files.

Comment: So unfortunately, that didn't seem to work, I had to revert back to the directory setting. It might be something to do with this - http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/457837/

Comment: Could be. I don't use CSS import in my style sheets.

Comment: I tested it on all OSs and it only works with the bundle being a directory.... Sorry I will have to unaccept your answer but I will definitely vote it up!